# Delphi XE and Winsock

Tags: delphi, upgrade, winsock, delphi-xe

I'm upgrading my application from Delphi 2007 to Delphi XE. I have my personal written Socket component. In the new environment (XE) it is not working properly. The same code works in Delphi 2007.

Here's my code fragment:

```
uses WinSock;

procedure TForm1.GetProtocolClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  ProtoEnt: PProtoEnt;
  FProtocol: Integer;
begin
  FProtocol := IPPROTO_TCP;
  ProtoEnt := getprotobynumber(FProtocol);
  if Assigned(ProtoEnt)
    then ShowMessage(ProtoEnt.p_name);
end;

var
  WSAData: TWSAData;

procedure Startup;
begin
  if WSAStartup($0101, WSAData) <> 0
  then raise Exception.Create('WSAStartup');
end;

procedure Cleanup;
begin
  if WSACleanup <> 0
  then raise Exception.Create('WSACleanup');
end;

initialization
  Startup;
finalization
  Cleanup;
end.
```

ProtoEnt is always not Assigned (i.e. = nil)!!!!!

WHY?

I am going crazy to solve this problem...
Thanks

Enzo

Comment: Please update your question. As it stands, the problem is not reproduced with the code you posted.  Update and fix your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you change your code a bit

```
procedure TForm1.GetProtocolClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  ProtoEnt: PProtoEnt;
  FProtocol: Integer;
begin
  FProtocol := IPPROTO_TCP;
  ProtoEnt := getprotobynumber(FProtocol);
  if Assigned(ProtoEnt)
    then ShowMessage(ProtoEnt.p_name)
    else ShowMessage(IntToStr(WSAGetLastError));
end;
```

you will see error code; after that check the [WinSock error codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I tried the next, it works perfectly on XE:

```
var
  WSAData: TWSAData;

procedure Startup;
begin
  if WSAStartup($0101, WSAData) <> 0
  then raise Exception.Create('WSAStartup');
end;

procedure Cleanup;
begin
  if WSACleanup <> 0
  then raise Exception.Create('WSACleanup');
end;

procedure TForm1.Button5Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ProtoEnt: PProtoEnt;
  FProtocol: Integer;
begin
  StartUp;
  FProtocol := IPPROTO_TCP;
  ProtoEnt := getprotobynumber(FProtocol);
  if Assigned(ProtoEnt)
    then ShowMessage(ProtoEnt.p_name)
    else ShowMessage(IntToStr(WSAGetLastError));
  CleanUp;
end;
```

Comment: The original code calls StarUp in the initialization section and raises an exception if it fails. What could be the root cause of the error?

Comment: @mjn I don't know; initialization code works for me too. Should be some local problem in OP code, not shown in the question.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but I have error #11004 (The requested name is valid, but does not have an Internet IP address at the name server)

Have you an idea?

Comment: @EnzoCostantini - Sorry, your problem is elsewhere. I tested your code and it works fine.

Comment: @EnzoCostantini - that's a DNS timeout. Try connecting using the IP address instead of the server name.